# ARKit convert ARFaceAnchor.lookAtPoint to world coordinates

Tags: swift, arkit

I am new to ARKit and I've been trying figure out the easiest way to plot an ARFaceAnchor's lookAtPoint into world coordinates, since they are provided relative to the face's current orientation (I believe). I've been trying to do this myself but I'm not confident that the answer is correct, I know there's some variability, but it seems to change too much if I stare at the same point while moving and rotating my head:

```
let faceMatrix = SCNMatrix4.init(currentFaceAnchor.transform);
let node = SCNNode();
node.transform = faceMatrix;
let eyeLocation = SCNVector3.init(currentFaceAnchor.lookAtPoint;)
node.localTranslate(by:eyeLocation!);
let eyeLocation = node.worldPosition;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi Brian, Did you find the solution for this? If yes could you please post the code snippet?